# Sum/Aggregate the 2 least values so that total2 will be > 2

Tags: t-sql

I have this table and I need to aggregate code1 if total2 <=2.
Basically roll it up/combine total to the next value least value so that field total2 will be >2 . How can I do it in t-sql?
Thank you for any help. I've been quite stumped on this.

Raw:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ad7f47b37d4694411b8a38db07356a7e

| code1 | code2 | total1 | total2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA1 | 123 | 9 | 3 |
| AAA1 | 120 | 3 | 5 |
| AAA1 | 124 | 4 | 2 |
| AAA2 | 125 | 2 | 1 |
| AAA2 | 126 | 3 | 2 |
| AAA3 | 121 | 4 | 4 |
| AAA5 | 119 | 1 | 1 |
| AAA6 | 118 | 4 | 2 |
| AAA6 | 117 | 2 | 5 |

Aggregated:

| code1 | code2 | total1 | total2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA1 | 120 | 3 | 5 |
| AAA1 | 123+124 | 13 | 5 |
| AAA2 | 125+126 | 5 | 3 |
| AAA3 | 121 | 4 | 4 |
| AAA5 | 119 | 1 | 1 |
| AAA6 | 118+117 | 6 | 7 |

Comment: Please do not post image. Post the sample data & expected result as formatted text. Also include your current query

Comment: What do you mean by `aggregate the least 2 values where total2>=2` ? Can you elaborate this further with example. And your question titled stated `where number <=2`. Which is the correct condition ?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo.. i'm trying to figure out how to do post the table one sec..

Comment: The fiddle is great but question should be self-contained. Please also include the sample data in the question as formatted text (as what you have done for the expected result)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to identify the least 2 rows based on `total2`. You can use a row_number()

```
row_number() over(partition by code1 order by total2)
```

Once you identified the `grp`, perform the aggregate on it (only for the least 2 rows `grp 2`)

for `total1` and `total2`, use `SUM()`, for `code2`, as it is string, use string aggregate [string_agg()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

---

Sample Data :

| code1 | code2 | total1 | total2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA1 | 123 | 9 | 3 |
| AAA1 | 120 | 3 | 5 |
| AAA1 | 124 | 4 | 2 |
| AAA2 | 125 | 2 | 1 |
| AAA2 | 126 | 3 | 2 |
| AAA3 | 121 | 4 | 4 |
| AAA5 | 119 | 1 | 1 |
| AAA6 | 118 | 4 | 2 |
| AAA6 | 117 | 2 | 5 |

```
with cte as
(
    select    *, 
              grp = case when row_number() over(partition by code1 
                                                    order by total2) <= 2
                         then 2
                         else 1
                         end
       from   Test1
)
select code1,
       code2 = case when grp = 1 then max(code2)
                    else string_agg(code2, '+') within group (order by code2)
                    end,
       total1 = case when grp = 1 then max(total1) else sum(total1) end,
       total2 = case when grp = 1 then max(total2) else sum(total2) end       
from   cte
group by code1, grp
order by code1, grp
```

Result :

| code1 | code2 | total1 | total2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA1 | 120 | 3 | 5 |
| AAA1 | 123+124 | 13 | 5 |
| AAA2 | 125+126 | 5 | 3 |
| AAA3 | 121 | 4 | 4 |
| AAA5 | 119 | 1 | 1 |
| AAA6 | 117+118 | 6 | 7 |

[fiddle<> demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e859e5f266a99ca4eb7d7c38a312a598)